# How to find a subdocument of a collection and update it with Mongoose/MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a basic document like so:

```
_id: fm393nrr,
name: 'My Event'
members: [{
   user: 94iru134nf
   attending: 1
}, {
   user: er9fr94,
   attending: 0
}]
```

How would I change a members `attending` based on their `user`?

For example, something like:

```
var eventToFind = 'fm393nrr'; //usually retrieved by req.params
var userToFind = 'er9fr94'; //usually retrieved by req.body.user

Event.findOneAndUpdate({
       _id: eventToFind
    }, {
       $set: {members.attending: {.....}}
    }
).exec(function(){....});
```

In the above, I am trying to set the member of `er9fr94` to have `attending` of 1. Code is very off, but was a long shot attempt. Never worked with subdocuments/embedded documents before.

Answer (score 1):

Add double quotes when dealing with nested objects. The `$` becomes equal to the array index of the match.

Try this:

```
Event.findOneAndUpdate({
   _id: eventToFind,
   "members.user":userToFind,
}, {
   $set: {"members.$.attending": {.....}}
})
```

Comment: So would I simply just do `$set: {"members.$.attending": 1}` to change their `attending`?

Comment: Yes. To change the attending of the `members` that matches `userToFind`.

Comment: maybe add `{upsert : true, new : true}` If you're having troubles